# ConstraintLayout horizontal positioning like a 'centerToCenterOf'

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Still couldn´t figure out how exactly you have to do the following with two views arranged inside a ConstraintLayout:
They are arranged vertically, so bottom one points to upper one with topToBottomOf. The upper one should have a fixed position done by startToStartOf and topToTopOf (+ margin etc.). Now the bottom one is vertically positioned as mentioned, but the horizontal positioning should be like a 'center to center of', meaning that it always shall adjust horizontally so that its center lies exactly below the center of the upper view.
Whenever I play around with chaining, the upper one immediatly jumps around and lose its original position, what kind of alienate me..
How that has to be done?

Update: The situation is like this:

[image]

4 Textviews, Textview 1 is the main anchor determining the overall position. Textview 3 always shall be rightside aligend to 1 with rightToRightOf. Now Textviews 2 and 4 shall always shift horizontally so that, as mentioned, their center is aligned with their directly upper Textview center. The widths of all Textviews can change and vary, depending on the text inserted by data binding

Comment: What about the width of the views ? `it always shall adjust horizontally so that its center lies exactly below the center of the upper view` - may not be possible depending on width of both views. Please post some code or attach an image of the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Note** that you may need to change dimensions (margins) of the views according to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="556dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.97" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:text="TextView 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="TextView 4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here

-> `TextView 1` is placed at any pos.

-> `TextView 2` is always center to center of `TextView 1` and below it.

-> `TextView 3` is right aligned to `TextView 1`

-> `TextView 4` is always center to center of `TextView 3` and below it.

Comment: holy moly, worked like a charm! the 'leftToLefOf' and 'rightToRightOf' of bottom views towards upper did it. would have thought it would squeeze them but no. thanks a lot